# Time between Visits

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, renewal-processes

This is a problem from [1] that I am struggling quite a bit with:

> Given an irreducible and positive recurrent DTMC, let $m_{ij}$ denote the mean number of steps to get
> from state i to state j. Either prove or disprove the following
> $$m_{jj} ≤ m_{ji} + m_{ij}$$

What I tried so far:

I proved that the probability of hitting state j starting from state i, $f_{ij}=1$ for any irreducible DTMC. So is it a pmf and $m_{ij} = \mathbb{E}[\text{hitting time}]$(We can probably apply some sort of renewal theory result on i-j). I also proved that this is true for a 2 state DTMC(Gilbert Elliot model), but I couldn't prove/find a counter-example for a more general case.

I also know that

$$m_{ii} \leq 1+(1-p_{ii})m_{ji} \leq m_{ij} + m_{ji}$$

for  $$j=\max_{k\neq i}\{m_{ki}\}$$

But again, nothing for a general j.

[1] *Harchol-Balter, Mor*, [**Performance modeling and design of computer systems. Queueing theory in action**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139226424.002), Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-1-107-02750-3/hbk; 978-1-139-60396-6/ebook). xxiii, 548 p. (2013). [ZBL1282.68007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1282.68007).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A start:** Let $R_k$ be the first return time to state $k$. Then, starting in state $j$,
$$
R_j=\min(R_i,R_j)+1_{\{R_i<R_j\}}\cdot (R_j-R_i).
$$
On the event $\{R_i<R_j\}$, the difference $R_j-R_i$ has the distribution of the first return to $j$ for the chain started in $i$. That is, by the strong Markov property,
$$
E^j[1_{\{R_i<R_j\}}\cdot (R_j-R_i)]= P^j[R_i<R_j]\cdot m_{ij}.
$$
(The superscript on $E^j$ indicates the initial state.)

Comment: That's a really nice way to write it. Thanks a lot!